# Three.js reset a 3dobject to it's original position/rotation/geometry before transformations

Tags: three.js

How can I reset or revert a 3dobject (such as a cube) to it's original state?

For example if I:

1. Create a `BufferGeometry` mesh at some starting position and rotation
2. Do some arbitrary transformations on it (such as change rotate or position etc..)
3. Then reset it back to it's original state.

I've tried doing something like this (but it doesn't work):

```
// MAKE A BACKUP OF ORIGINAL OBJECT
const backup = mesh.clone();
mesh.userData['backup'] = backup;

// --- DO SOME TRANSFORMATIONS ON `mesh` HERE ---

// RESET THE ORIGINAL
mesh.position.copy(mesh.userData['backup'].position);
mesh.rotation.copy(mesh.userData['backup'].rotation);
mesh.matrix.copy(mesh.userData['backup'].matrix);
mesh.geometry.copy(mesh.userData['backup'].geometry);
mesh.quaternion.copy(mesh.userData['backup'].quaternion);
```

I've also tried adding the backup to scene and deleting the original, but this is problematic because there is `userData` and draggable stuff attached the original that doesn't get cloned.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept and upvote my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
var backupGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(mesh1Size, mesh1Size, mesh1Size);
var backupMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: //anything});
var backup = new THREE.Mesh(backupGeometry, backupMaterial);

// --- DO SOME TRANSFORMATIONS ON mesh HERE ---

mesh.position.copy(backup.position);
mesh.rotation.copy(backup.rotation);

//etc.
```

You don't need to add the clone to userData.

Comment: This should work, did it not?